# how to add external html page to wordpress page using plugin

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I want to add an external html page to a wordpress page. Like "http://mysite.com.au/wp-content/bootstrap-3.3.6/bootstrap-3.3.6/docs/examples/grid/index.html" this is the page i want to show on "http://mysite.com.au/calculator" this page. I dont want to redirect it.
Is there any plugin or solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

the fastest way is to use an iframe.

```
<iframe src="http://example.com/" frameborder="no" width="" height="" ></iframe>
```